# "Sites I'm following" shows old urls after Migration from SP13 to SP16

Tags: user-profile, mysite, following

we have migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016. We migrated User profile service application as per the Microsoft guideline. After migration, we see old URLs in "Sites I'm following" section of mysite. if we follow new site then its getting updated in "Sites I'm following" list. But we need to update existing(wrong) sites with new url.

Is there any way to do the same? from powershell or from SQL side. Also are we missing any steps in Migrating User profile service appliaction?